# Is an algebraic extension of a separably closed field separably closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

In the book ["Rational points on varieties" by Bjorn Poonen](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/Qpoints.pdf), exercise 1.1 (a) states:

> "Prove that an algebraic extension of a separably closed field is
> separably closed."

Is this even true?
I believe that, by definition of a separable closure, any nontrivial algebraic extension would actually be inseparable.

Also, part (c) mentions the perfect closure of the separable closure: $ (k_s)^{perf} $. However, does this always exist? Or is this question maybe just about fields where this exists? (I believe these would be fields $ k $ such that $ k_s = \bar{k} $).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the first statement is true. There is no contradiction with what you write: indeed, the strategy for the problem is to decompose the algebraic extension as a separable extension followed by a purely inseparable extension, note that the separable extension must be trivial, and then argue from there.

The answer to your second question is also yes: you can take the perfect closure of any field $k$. One way to do this is to embed $k$ in to an algebraic closure $\overline{k}$ and then take all the elements $x\in \overline{k}$ so that $x^{p^n}\in k$ for some $n$.

Comment: Hm... Right. So separability is a property of extensions, not of fields themselves? (Because any algebraic extension $k_s \subset L$ will be inseparable, but since then any extension $L \subset L^\prime$ of that will be inseparable, $L$ is still considered to be separably closed, even though $L$ is an inseparable extension of $k_s$?)

Comment: Yes, separability and inseparability are properties of field extensions. On the other hand, being separably closed is a property of a field.

Comment: Hm... Right. Then all this makes sense.